# Wordpress the "Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields" plugin support for qTranslateX other fields translation

Tags: php, localization, wordpress, qtranslate-x

Is there a settings, option or a plugin to allow the "More Fields" of the edit.php page to be localized in the selected language ?

At the moment I can only translate the Title field and any other wp fields.
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to:

- open qTranslateX settings
- show the "Custom Integration" group
- in the id text entry writing all the pods id's, e.g: pods-form-ui-pods-meta-myitem separated by space or comma
- Save changes

Opening some pod page item in edit.php will add a blue rectangular border in the left side, while the other fields will have no border at all.

Hope this will help someone :).

jQuery code to list all the id's:

```
var fields = "";

jQuery("[id^=pods-form-ui-pods-meta]").each(function(i, item){
    fields += " " + jQuery(item).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the quickest and cleanest way of doing this!